# Connection refused for socket created on secondary/dummy IP

Tags: java, linux, sockets, networking

I have created two dummy IP addresses on the eth0 interface of my machine by using the command:

```
sudo ip address add 10.1.1.10/24 dev eth0
sudo ip address add 10.1.1.11/24 dev eth0
```

They show up like this:

```
ip address show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
....
inet 10.1.1.10/24 scope global eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.1.1.11/24 scope global secondary eth0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
.....
```

Now, I want to create a server-client connection on these two interfaces. However the code which I wrote is throwing the following error, when I just started the server code.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at Server.main(Server.java:12)
```

Following is my server-code:

```
        try {
        ServerSocket ssoc = new ServerSocket(60000, 0, InetAddress.getByName("10.1.1.10"));
        Socket clientSocket = ssoc.accept();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        while (true) {
            String str = "Hello Client";
            osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
            osw.flush();
            char[] input = new char[5000];
            while(isr.ready()) {
                isr.read(input, 0, input.length);
            }
            System.out.println("Client: " + new String(input));
        }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I don't know what I am missing here. One of the thoughts that I had was that maybe the socket() requires some kind of route to the 10.1.1.x network, but that is just a vague thought. Kindly help.

Edit: I have edited the Server code above according to EJP's suggestion in comments. Following is my Client code, and now the two codes are communicating.

```
try {
            Socket soc = new Socket("10.1.1.10", 60000);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            while (true) {
                String str = "Hello Server";
                osw.write(str, 0, str.length());
                osw.flush();
                char[] input = new char[5000];
                while(isr.ready()) {
                    isr.read(input, 0, input.length);
                }
                System.out.println("Server: " + new String(input));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you connect to your server using `telnet` or `nc` (netcat)?

Comment: This is not server code. It is client code. It needs a server, with a `ServerSocket`. Is there one? NB Your read loop is radically defective.

Comment: @EJP, agreed. I'll change that.

Comment: You'll change it when? That was three hours ago. and you still haven't posted the real server code. 'Connection refused' means exactly one thing: nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. No mystery.

Comment: @EJP, yeah was caught up with something else and then this body needs its sleep. Anyways, thanks for the help, it is working now.